# Include and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I need to make one connection to the database and use it everywhere in my PHP files. I understand include but maybe I don't fully. If I make a PHP file with the functions to connect to a database and leave a variable for it, then include that file in 2 PHP files. Will there be 2 connections? How can I just make one single connection and use the variable everywhere?

Also note that I'm going to use PDO, it would be better if you provide help with PDO's syntax.

Comment: As long as each PHP file only includes the connection file once then it wont create another instance of the variable however i imagine your php file will declare the variable like $db = connection so the variable we be overwritten

Comment: Will it make a new connection each time I include the PHP file or just allow access to the variable? That's my real question.

Comment: Yes every time the script ends the variables end along with it - so does the connection so it will drop the connection and create a new one when a new page is visited unless you store the connection in a session or cookie however i would not recommend doing this

Comment: if the real question is how to keep a connection to a database open throughout a users visit to your website then you are best serialising the connection variable and sorting it as a session of sorts and on another page load unserialise the string if it exists and make the variable available again

Comment: @Sephedo I don't think OP is meaning separate requests (OP can clarify). I assumed they meant across various stages and files executed as part of a single request

Comment: @Sephedo Also, DB connections cannot be serialised, they are transitive. PDO offers persistent connections but I doubt OP is going to need them

Comment: All I need is not to open 5 connections if I need to access the database in 5 different PHP files to improve performance.

Comment: The connection will not be created lots of times by the same user it will be dropped when the script ends and a new one will start the next page load

Comment: @Sephedo It appears you were correct; OP is talking about separate execution / request cycles. You should add that information as an answer

Comment: @Phil Yes it appears so - nice pointing out the serialisation of pdo object never found a need to do it so nice to know its limitations the only way then i would think which i have done previously is to have a service like class to store the connection and it run regardless if the user aborts the script so its always accessible (like a runtime php service sort of speak)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The database will connect each time a *page* loads, regardless of how many php files are included in the page load.

So, you can limit the number of connections to one per page load.

In order to do this, you create a connection file, containing something along the lines of:

```
$user = 'database_username';
$pass = 'a_Hard_Password';
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $user, $pass);
```

You will then save that file, naming it something like `db.php` or similar.

Then, in whichever files you need to use the database, you will include the file *one time* by utilizing `require_once`, as follows:

```
require_once 'db.php';

$results = $db->query('SELECT * FROM my_table');
foreach($results AS $row) {
    var_dump($row);
}
```

There's plenty of good resources out there, and this is simply an example, but for a more complex query, one of the advantages of PDO is bound parameters, like so:

```
$id = 5; // Or some other useful value
$name = 'James'; // Or your desired query value
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE id=? AND name=?");
$stmt->execute(array($id, $name));
$results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
foreach($results AS $row) {
    // The PDO::FETCH_ASSOC parameter tells it to return an associative array...
    echo $row['id'];
    echo $row['name'];
   // ... etc ...
}
```